# Visual Studio 2015 - Stuck at Splash Screen

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to load VS2015 Pro Version (update 3) in Windows 10 and I have been fighting with this for a few days trying different things. When I launch it, I go to the white Visual Studio Splash Screen and it just hangs. This was seen a lot in VS2013 and apparently in VS2015 also but nothing has worked so far.

Anyone have a success story they can share?

Based on various sites, I have tried:
     1.devenv.exe /safemode
     2.devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
     3.devenv.exe /installvstemplates
     4.devenv.exe /resetsettings
     5.devenv.exe /resetuserdata

I was able to run devenv.exe /resetsettings and I get in but I immediately have errors and then Visual Studio Locks and I can't click anything. When I click close on the popups I get an error that VS Stopped Working and I am in VS but it is locked. I am unable to click on anything.

Errors when I do get in:

```
  CommonAzureToolsPackage did not load correctly.
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage  did not load correctly.
```

My ActivityLog.xml has this:

```
             <type>Error</type>
            <source>VisualStudio</source>
            <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected&apos; Description: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Common.CommonUtilities.CheckAndResetUserTokenStorage(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.&#x000D;&#x000A;To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.&#x000D;&#x000A;To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
            <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
            <hr>80070002</hr>
            <errorinfo></errorinfo>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <record>26</record>
            <time>2016/10/15 03:38:42.027</time>
            <type>Error</type>
            <source>VisualStudio</source>
            <description>SetSite failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage](null)</description>
            <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
            <hr>80070002</hr>
            <errorinfo></errorinfo>
          </entry>
          <entry>
            <record>27</record>
            <time>2016/10/15 03:38:42.042</time>
            <type>Error</type>
            <source>VisualStudio</source>
            <description>End package load        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage]</description>
            <guid>{7F679D93-2EB6-47C9-85EB-F6AD16902662}</guid>
            <hr>80070002</hr>
            <errorinfo></errorinfo>
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue? I have a similar problem, it looks like the version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client in GAC is 12.0.0.0 (probably from the previous version of VS) instead of 14.0.0.0

Comment: Hey Romanaza I did not. After looking at multiple sites and being in the MS Forum they suggested reloading my O/S and seeing what happens. I think this is similar to tech support saying "reboot".  This was the thread on MS Forum which had some links that I also tried but at this time, I just stuck with VS2013 for now.  You may want to see if any of these help. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/916e7f13-f58b-4277-ae9f-c7ac4afa7441/vs-pro-2015-hanging?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem today with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (probably because I manually deleted the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14 directory in between uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio.) I checked a working machine and found that my machine was missing the file **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll** in the following directories:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\qngmizal.tmp

**Note:** The latter directory has a randomly generated name, but the directory can be identified by the presence of an **extension.vsixmanifest** file that contains the following element:

```
<Identity Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Extensions" Version="14.0.23102" Language="en-US" Publisher="Microsoft"/>
```

**Update:** As you correctly note, the first directory is actually a symbolic link to the second one.

Uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio didn't fix the problem. **Repairing Visual Studio did.**

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will look at this tonight. I just checked my work laptop and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer is a link to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\lv5t0um4.beo file.

Comment: Additional...I tried the repair a few times and no luck. I did see a post about Team Explorer from people who had the issue in VS2013 but there was a stand alone Team Explorer they installed that resolved the issue. Apparently that is no longer stand alone in 2015 so I did not find a download for it, Maybe I can copy the files over. Appreciate the help.

Comment: ok looked at this tonight. I am missing the entire Team Explorer Directory. Doing some research but why is this not %$^# loaded on install???

Comment: Does the following registry key exist on your system? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\EA592197A0B32223E996628C1C608E1D\InstallProperties

Comment: that does not exist!

Comment: I ran C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe /resetsettings

Comment: Man I hate that the enter key loads the comment here. Anyway I ran the above command and that opened up VS which through 2 errors at me. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.ConnectedUserPackage did not load correctly. The other was CommonAzureToolsPackage did not load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem you were (and the same issues getting any suggested solution to work), and finally- *finally* got it to go by running [msiinv](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2005/07/01/using-msiinv-to-gather-information-about-what-is-installed-on-a-computer/) on the machine and using msiexec to pull everything that shared the same version number as my installation media (for our version of VS2015, 14.0.254xx). It was lengthy and annoying as heck, but once I finished, VS installed correctly.

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: Whew, sorry about answering so late! Basically, you run msiinv to get a list of all the MSIs installed on a box. It'll give you the product codes for everything, which you use to run msiexec.exe /x {your-product-code-guid} for every MSI related to that version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this morning, I lanched Dev Studio 2015 and it hung in hte splash screen. Tried restarting it - still hung. Note I also the Everything file finder app and its service (which is great app I use all the time). The Everything  service was not running. I started the service and then devenv.exe burst into life immediately.